# Issue with Selenium, BS and pandas "ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length"

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am a total noob in coding, but am currently working on some stuff just to play around in python - which is really cool!

Can you help me figure out a way on how to avoid the "ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length" in case some partial data (e.g. price) is not availabe on a website I want to crawl? I can see that the data is not available through print(len) - for example the dataframe has then a len of 10,11,11, which causes the error, because the first is missing a row value. Everything else works just fine. For me it would be cool if the missing line could simply be filled with something like "-" or "Not available".

I tried reading a lot and am suffering a lot of trial and error, therefore, would be really glad if someone could help me out. Here is my code:

```
    #add parser
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
            
    #add scrape info
    images = []
    for img in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'gridContent'}):
        images.append(img.get('src'))
        marke  = [marke.text for marke in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'ZZZ'})]
        titel  = [titel.text for titel in soup.findAll('h3', {'class': 'YYY'})]
        preis  = [preis.text for preis in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'XXX'})]
                          
        #assign DF's
        alle_daten = {'Zeitstempel:': timestamp_human, 'URL:': url, 'Marke:': marke, 'Titel:': titel, 'Preis:': preis}
                              
        df_all = pd.DataFrame(data=alle_daten) 
                      
        df_scrape_all_clean = df_all.replace('\n', ' ',)
        clean_stack = pd.concat([df_scrape_all_clean], axis=1)
        df_all_urls = df_all_urls.append(df_all)
                       
    df_all_urls.to_excel("AAA.xlsx")
    print(url)
```

Comment: This is the section where the code keeps crashing: 
#assign DF's
alle_daten = {'Zeitstempel:': timestamp_human, 'URL:': url, 'Marke:': marke, 'Titel:': titel, 'Preis:': preis}

Comment: You can check if price is None, and append N/A when price is not available.

Comment: @KamaleshS: Can you explain to me how this is possible? This would - at least i guess so - fix my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I can help you out better if you can share the url.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example with a case study to understand why this error comes and how to avoid it in the future.

Suppose we attempt to create the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

#define arrays to use as columns in DataFrame
team = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
position = ['G', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'F', 'F']
points = [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9, 9, 4]

#attempt to create DataFrame from arrays
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': team,
                   'position': position,
                   'points': points})

result:

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

We receive an error that tells us each array does not have the same length.

We can verify this by printing the length of each array:

```
#print length of each array
print(len(team), len(position), len(points))

result:

7 8 8
```

We see that the ‘team’ array only has 7 elements while the ‘position’ and ‘points’ arrays each have 8 elements.

**How to Fix the Error**

The easiest way to address this error is to simply make sure that each array we use has the same length:

```
import pandas as pd

#define arrays to use as columns in DataFrame
team = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
position = ['G', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'F', 'F']
points = [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9, 9, 4]

#create DataFrame from arrays
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': team,
                   'position': position,
                   'points': points})

#view DataFrame
df

    team    position points
0   A   G    5
1   A   G    7
2   A   F    7
3   A   F    9
4   B   G    12
5   B   G    9
6   B   F    9
7   B   F    4
```

Notice that each array has the same length this time.

Thus, when we use the arrays to create the pandas DataFrame we don’t receive an error because each column has the same length.

Comment: Thanks @Zakaria Ferzazi  for your impressive response. But the issue here is, that I do not create the dataframe data manually but I scrape it from a website. Therefore, I cannot simply add "one more value". I would need to automatically add a "Not available" or something like that while creating the dataframe, in case values are missing. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: i understand you dear, listen try this: `alle_daten = pd.DataFrame({'Zeitstempel:': timestamp_human, 'URL:': url, 'Marke:': marke, 'Titel:': titel, 'Preis:': preis})
df_all_urls= pd.ExcelWriter('AAA.xlsx')
df_all.to_excel(writer)
df_all_urls.save()`